# MyPy fails with TypeAlias?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, type-alias

**MyPy** (v 1.1.0) appears to fail with **TypeAlias**.

```
StrBytes: TypeAlias = str | bytes
var: type[StrBytes] = StrBytes
```

Is signaled by **mypy** with the following error:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type 
"<typing special form>", variable has type "type[str] | type[bytes]")
```

Is this a bug with mypy?

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Python v 3.11.6

Comment: If it's any help, pyright doesn't report an error and I've generally found it more reliable